# How to arrange the material top tab navigator tab name in a single line on react native?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-tabnavigator

I want to arrange the material top tab navigator name in a single line.

The first tab name is lengthy here, so it displays in two lines. Like this (img_1).

[img_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC7Jz.png)

But I want to convert the name to a single line. Like this (img_2).

[img_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ipl1T.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to try this.

```
     <Tab.Navigator 
     screenOptions={{
      tabBarItemStyle: {
        width: 'auto',
        minWidth: '100',
        alignItems: 'center',
      },
    }} >
```

Comment: it's working but overflowing to the right side. I want to add the ellipsize.

Comment: @Sirilmp You can refer this:  https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/2112

Comment: This is working with the length of the name but I want to work with the device width.